# Python - string replacement in a weird way;

Tags: python, string, replace

Anyone can help with this? Imagine the following:

```
def example(s):
    s = s.replace('foo', 'foo bar')
    return s
```

Now this will replace 'foo' with 'foo bar'; But I want to do something a bit different:
 * Imagine I have 'foo something'; I want the final result to be: 'foo something bar'

What would be the best way to make such check (if there is a 'something', I want to preserve it).

Anyone can help please ?

NM

Comment: so you just want to append `bar` to your original word? or just to the word that follows `foo`?

Comment: Do you always want to just append bar?  Or only when the original string contains foo?

Comment: I'm parsing a file, and if I get:

`%find_lang %{name}`

I want it to be replaced by

`%find_lang %{name} %{?no_lang_C}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `re` module.

```
import re
def replace(s):
     return re.sub('foo(.*)', 'foo\1 bar', s)
replace('foo something') #'foo something bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
mystring = "foo something blah"
re.sub(r"foo\s+(\w+)", r"foo \1 bar", mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example you mention above:

```
import re

text = """Line 1 %find_lang %{name} has two %find_lang %{name}
occurences.

Line 4 has one %find_lang %{name}.

%find_lang %{name}

Line 6 is just the search pattern and a new line."""

print re.sub(
        '%find_lang %{name}',
        '%find_lang %{name} %{?no_lang_C}',
        text
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For the exercise, a clunky way that doesn't use regexp:

```
def replace_foo(arg):
   content = arg.split()
   idx_foo = content.index("foo")
   content.insert(idx_foo+2, "bar")
   return ' '.join(content)
```

(but you should really use `re`...)

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed it with the following:

```
def replace_lang_macros(s):
    return re.sub(r'%find_lang(.*)', r'%find_lang\1 %{?no_lang_C}', s)
```

Thanks all; No matter what stands after %find_lang it remains there... Without raw string notation I get strange symbols, but that wasn't much of a challenge.